# Mezuza in a room with a television

Tags: halacha, bathroom, performance-entertainment

Of course watching things other than kosher things on a television is Asur, that's not my question. My question is that if one has a television in a room and watches it for things that all agree are forbidden (Perisut etc.) does he place a Mezuza there?

I've heard in the name of Harav Meir Mazuz that one shouldn't place a Mezuza there as it has the same legal status as a bathroom in this regard.

CYLOR & sources please

Comment: My guess, and it is only a guess, is this. I would doubt that most orthodox rabbis would tell a secular Jew not to place a mezuzah on their front door knowing that they desicrate shabbbat and kashrut. Every mitzvah counts. Since watching television (even, ehem, porn) is not universally accepted as an aveira, I would assume that placing a mezuzah on room used for watching TV would be acceptable. In Olam Habah, how will the mitzvah of mezuzah balance watching TV? Who knows but Hashem, but I suspect, even if watching television is an averiarah, the mitzvah of mezuzah will be greater.

Comment: Nothing to do with being Mekayem another Miswa, it's just that Perisut would invalidate the room from a Mezuza possibly.

Comment: HG, that is only assuming having a television is inappropriate. I disagree with that assumption. Applying your implied logic, wouldn't bringing pork into a house invalidate the entire house from placing a mezuzah on the front door? Who would disourage even the most secular Jew from having a mezuzah? So what about a television would make the room that it is located in the same status as a bathroom? The posters question may be one of the "ask your rabbi" nature. The answer to the question seems specific to the particular community the poster belongs to.

Comment: Jeffery, I didn't say having a Tv is inappropriate, I said if someone watches innappropriate things on a Tv then does he place a Mezuza on the door of the room where he watches Perisut?

Comment: Is watching asur TV the only thing done in that room ever, or do you also do other things there?

Comment: PS.  Ironic ruling for someone whose name is Mazuz :)

Comment: Hi HG. I most certainly understand your point. As I asked, HG, would you not pit a mezuzah on the door of a house that the owner

Comment: @HachamGabriel a mi9wo is a mi9wo. it doesnt depend on anything else. its like saying in all the rooms where you make an aveiro you should remove the mazuzo.

Comment: Hi HG. I most certainly understand your point. Of course most--not all mind you--people don't have a dedicated theater/Media room so many things are likely done (other than watching inappropriate TV) in the room in question. I understand that. I'm just suggesting that the concept of "inappropriate" may be broader than you might think. I'll ask my rabbi your question this Shabbat and let you know what he says. In the meantime, have a Good Shabbos HG. (And everyone else on this thread.)

Comment: By the way, ignore the previous post, the tunkated one that is, it was added in error.

Comment: Don't know why, but an earlier post has been deleted. I asked my OR and he said a mezuzah goes on the door post.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Rema YD 286:2, a mezuzah is required on a room in a house even if it is used for bathing.
Since we always cover our mezuzahs, all opinions agree that a mezuzah is required (see Shach s.k. 9)

A television has no relation to a bathroom, which does not have a mezuzah because of dirat kavod, and a living room is a proper dwelling place, even if you watch things you shouldn't.